# Save multiple values of checkbox selected items and show values in next activity?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I was stuck with this problem from long.
I want to save values of all selected checkbox items from a recyclerview list and then when clicking on a Button,I want to show the values in the next activity.
I am using firebase cloud firestore database and kotlin for coding.

This is my checkbox screen(whose selected values I want to access and store):

[image]

this is my next blank activity(which will open on clicking host button) where i want to show the name of all selected users from previous activity{

[image]

Can someone provide me with a workable solution,please help!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: try to add some codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store your values as a Boolean array and then send it to another activity by intent

```
val intent = Intent().apply { arguments = Bundle().putBooleanArray("key", array) }
```

Comment: ok thank you.I was storing the value in an ArrayList and was doing something wrong.But now it works fine.

Comment: You are welcome. You can also easily convert your list to array in Kotlin. Just use  toTypedArray() function. val array = list.toTypedArray()